# When I click on the turn button I want the name, age and location to show up? How to get access to the nextContestant variable in the function?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, iterator

The problem is that the buttonSound function has no reference to the currentContestant variable which is in the nextContestant function, and I'm having trouble fixing that any help would be appreciated ty. I've tried declaring it globally but it didn't help tried calling function b inside function a and that didn't work. Im sure it is some simple fix that I'm not quite getting.

```js
// Temporary hardcoded data
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Dua Lipa',
        age: 22,
        location: 'UK',
        song: 'Arctic Monkeys - Do I Wanna Know?',
        link:'https://www.youtube.com/embed/fZB-ptAnoQc?start=26'
    },
    {
        name: 'James Arthur',
        age: 23,
        location: 'UK',
        song: 'Frankie Vallie - Cant Take my Eyes Off you',
        link:'https://www.youtube.com/embed/JUeEcdS-aa0?start=12'
       
    },
    
];


document.querySelector('.turn-button').addEventListener('click', buttonSound);

// Create event for next button
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', nextContestant);


// pass the data in the profileIterator function
const contestants = profileIterator(data);


// Call first profile
nextContestant();




// Next profile Display
function nextContestant() {
    const currentContestant = contestants.next().value;
   
 
    // Add a condition if it finishes looping through the array
    if(currentContestant !== undefined){
    document.querySelector('#profileDisplay').innerHTML = `
    <iframe class="hidden-vid" width="560" height="315" src="${currentContestant.link}&rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=2" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div id="imageDisplay"><img class="anon"
                            src="media/anon.png"></div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" id="name">Name: ? 
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item" id="age">Age: ?
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item" id="location">Location: ?
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item">Song: ${currentContestant.song} 
        </li>
    </ul>
    `;
    } else {
        // No more contestants
        window.location.reload();
    }
    return {
        contestant: currentContestant
    }

    // document.querySelector('#imageDisplay').innerHTML = `<img
    // src="${currentContestant.image}">`;
}

// Profile Iterator
function profileIterator(contestants) {
    // counter
let nextIndex = 0;

// return object with next function
return {
    next: function(){
        return nextIndex < contestants.length ?
        {value: contestants[nextIndex++], done: false} :
        {done: true}
    }
};

}



function buttonSound(){

    const sound = document.querySelector('#audio');
    sound.play();
    document.querySelector(".anon").style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector("iFrame").style.display='block';
    document.querySelector("#name").innerText=`Name: ${currentContestant.name}`;
    document.querySelector("#age").innerText=`Age: ${currentContestant.age}`;
    document.querySelector("#location").innerText=`Location: ${currentContestant.location}`;
    // document.querySelector('#imageDisplay').innerHTML = `<img
    // src="${currentContestant.image}">`;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.turn-button {
    padding: 3rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0.3rem solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem black;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-self: center;
}

/* :active an element being activated by a user */
.turn-button:active {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    box-shadow: 0rem 1rem black;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}

.next {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10rem;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.stage {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /* width: 100%; */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); */
    z-index: -1;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); */
    z-index: -1;
}

.profile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 6%;
}

.judges-panel {
    display: flex;
    background-color: grey;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

iframe {
    display: none;
}

img {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="stage">
            <video id="videoBG" poster="media/poster.png" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="media/vid-background.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div class="container profile">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center">
                        <h1 class="mb-3"></h1>
                        <br />
                        <div id="profileDisplay"></div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="judges-panel">
            <button class="turn-button">TURN</button>
            <audio id="audio" src="media/button-sound.mp3"></audio>
            <button class="next">Next Contestant</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- <iframe class="hidden-vid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c8m6kBF5ML8?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=2" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
       
        
        </iframe>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you're really asking is that we spend hours reading your 250 lines of code to understand and possibly find a solution. Might as well talk about torture. You should simplify your question to reduce it to something digestible, as recommended on this site; read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I agree. the answer might be simple... but this is written in such a strange way that It might not even be worth looking for it. I mean you have an `</iframe>` closing tag without any `<iframe>` opening tag

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with scope; var is function scoped, let is block scoped, and const is for variables which are have a fixed value which can't be changed (a constant variable). You have `currentContestant` defined as a constant with scope inside the function `nextContestant` which doesn't make sense as it changes value every player turn.  If you want to make it a global, define it as `var nextContestant = null;` outside of any function.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Peter Brand's answer, it indeed has something to do with scope. Since you define the variable in the function it is not available in the global scope. I added the variable to the script you posted and ran it on CodePen and it seems like everything is working :)

```
// Temporary hardcoded data
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Dua Lipa',
        age: 22,
        location: 'UK',
        song: 'Arctic Monkeys - Do I Wanna Know?',
        link:'https://www.youtube.com/embed/fZB-ptAnoQc?start=26'
    },
    {
        name: 'James Arthur',
        age: 23,
        location: 'UK',
        song: 'Frankie Vallie - Cant Take my Eyes Off you',
        link:'https://www.youtube.com/embed/JUeEcdS-aa0?start=12'
       
    },
    
];


document.querySelector('.turn-button').addEventListener('click', buttonSound);

// Create event for next button
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', nextContestant);


// pass the data in the profileIterator function
const contestants = profileIterator(data);

let currentContestant;

// Call first profile
nextContestant();

// Next profile Display
function nextContestant() {

    currentContestant = contestants.next().value;

    // Add a condition if it finishes looping through the array
    if(currentContestant !== undefined){
    document.querySelector('#profileDisplay').innerHTML = `
    <iframe class="hidden-vid" width="560" height="315" src="${currentContestant.link}&rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=2" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div id="imageDisplay"><img class="anon"
                            src="media/anon.png"></div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" id="name">Name: ? 
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item" id="age">Age: ?
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item" id="location">Location: ?
        </li>
        <li class ="list-group-item">Song: ${currentContestant.song} 
        </li>
    </ul>
    `;
    } else {
        // No more contestants
        window.location.reload();
    }
    return {
        contestant: currentContestant
    }

    // document.querySelector('#imageDisplay').innerHTML = `<img
    // src="${currentContestant.image}">`;
}

// Profile Iterator
function profileIterator(contestants) {
    // counter
let nextIndex = 0;

// return object with next function
return {
    next: function(){
        return nextIndex < contestants.length ?
        {value: contestants[nextIndex++], done: false} :
        {done: true}
    }
};

}



function buttonSound(){
    const sound = document.querySelector('#audio');
    sound.play();
    document.querySelector(".anon").style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector("iFrame").style.display='block';
    document.querySelector("#name").innerText=`Name: ${currentContestant.name}`;
    document.querySelector("#age").innerText=`Age: ${currentContestant.age}`;
    document.querySelector("#location").innerText=`Location: ${currentContestant.location}`;
    // document.querySelector('#imageDisplay').innerHTML = `<img
    // src="${currentContestant.image}">`;
}
```

Comment: Hey Faris! thank you for having a look at my code, but it still isn't working? Does name, age and location appear for you when you clicked on the push button ?

Comment: Hey marcCodez, I have edited the script I posted slightly. I saw that you defined the variable "currentContestant" twice, once in the function and once in the global scope. In the edited script I added it as a global variable BEFORE the nextContestant script runs. This allows both functions to be able to use the currentContestant variable :)